# Potential Energy of Damped Oscillator

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator, dissipation

In the case of a simple harmonic oscillator we know that the total energy of the system is given as

$$E=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2$$

where the potential is

$$U=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$$

I read that if instead we are working with a damped oscillator the expression for potential energy would be the same. I understand that the expression for position and velocity have the decaying exponential so the total energy will be decreasing as expected but why doesn't the potential energy expression need to be changed in this the case? When getting an expression for potential energy wouldn't we need to also consider the resistive force as well?

Comment: The expression for potential energy would be the same because the work done by the interaction $\vec{F}=-k \vec{x}$ is still given by it. The difference is that there is a new interaction, responsible for the damping, which is doing work as well, extracting energy from the system.

Comment: The **expressions** for both kinetic and potential energy do not change. The dynamics of the system determines new *v(t)* and *x(t)* which in turn determines new **values** for both energies.

Comment: Recall:  potential energy is the energy of *position* (or *configuration*).  Kinetic energy is the energy of *motion*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good old-fashioned definition of potential energy is the amount of work a body can do by virtue of its position. So when a body goes between positions A and B its change in potential energy is the same, independently of the route it takes or how fast it goes. If it goes from A to B and back to A its net change in potential energy is zero.

This applies to a body doing (natural) shm. The body's potential energy is a function of its distance $x$ from the equilibrium position.

Damping forces do not give rise to potential energy. If a body goes from A to B and back again to A, the net work, $\int {\vec{F}.\vec{dx}}$, will not be zero, if $\vec{F}$ is a frictional or resistive force, dependent on direction of motion.